# No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"adverts", :userr_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:userr_id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to ruby on rails and any help would be much appreciated. i am unsure on how to go about resolving my error. I think i am meant to do more in my controller but i am confused as this is a nested resources challenge i am facing

i am trying to view the details of an advert (show) in my views, but when i click the link `show` i get the below error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"adverts", :userr_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:userr_id]

ActionController::UrlGenerationError (No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"adverts", :userr_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:userr_id]):
  app/views/shared/_header_recruiter.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_shared__header_recruiter_html_erb___2254802171992378619_70258749378740'
  app/views/adverts/show.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_adverts_show_html_erb___3448815807687044417_70258749644120'
  app/controllers/adverts_controller.rb:26:in `show'
```

i have adverts nested under userr (recruiters) - routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :userrs
  resources :userrs do
    resources :adverts
  end

  devise_for :userjs
  root    'static_pages#homepg'
  get     'search',       to: 'static_pages#searchpg'
end
```

i created a static page called searching - static_pages_controller.rb

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :xml, :json

  def searchpg
    @adverts = Advert.all
  end  
end
```

i have the below codings in my searching view file - searchpg.html.erb

```
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Published</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Content</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <% @adverts.each do |advert| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= advert.created_at.strftime("%B %d, %Y") %></td>
          <td><%= link_to advert.title, '#' %></td>
          <td><%= advert.content %></td>
          <td><%= advert.city %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Show', userr_advert_path(advert.userr, advert) %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

theses are my routes:

```
 userr_adverts GET    /userrs/:userr_id/adverts(.:format)          adverts#index
                          POST   /userrs/:userr_id/adverts(.:format)          adverts#create
         new_userr_advert GET    /userrs/:userr_id/adverts/new(.:format)      adverts#new
        edit_userr_advert GET    /userrs/:userr_id/adverts/:id/edit(.:format) adverts#edit
             userr_advert GET    /userrs/:userr_id/adverts/:id(.:format)      adverts#show
                          PATCH  /userrs/:userr_id/adverts/:id(.:format)      adverts#update
                          PUT    /userrs/:userr_id/adverts/:id(.:format)      adverts#update
                          DELETE /userrs/:userr_id/adverts/:id(.:format)      adverts#destroy
```

i already have an adverts controller:

```
class AdvertsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :xml, :json
  before_action :set_advert, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @userr = Userr.find(params[:userr_id])
    @adverts = @userr.adverts.order("created_at DESC")
    respond_with(@adverts)
  end

  def show
    @userr = Userr.find(params[:userr_id])
    @advert = @userr.adverts.find(params[:id]) 
    respond_with(@advert)
  end

  def new
    @userr = Userr.find(params[:userr_id])
    @advert = @userr.adverts.build
    respond_with(@advert)
  end

  def edit
    @userr = Userr.find(params[:userr_id])
    @advert = @userr.adverts.find(params[:id]) 
  end

  def create
    @userr = Userr.find(params[:userr_id])
    @advert = @userr.adverts.create(advert_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @advert.save
        format.html { redirect_to([@advert.userr, @advert], notice: 'Advert was successfully created.') }
        format.json  { render json: @advert, status: :created, location: @advert }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json  { render json: @advert.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    @userr = Userr.find(params[:userr_id])
    @advert = @userr.adverts.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @advert.update_attributes(advert_params)
        format.html { redirect_to([@advert.userr, @advert], notice: 'Advert was successfully updated.') }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @advert.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @userr = Userr.find(params[:userr_id])
    @advert = @userr.adverts.find(params[:id])
    @advert.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      #1st argument reference the path /recruiters/:recruiter_id/adverts/
      format.html { redirect_to(recruiter_adverts_url) }
      format.json  { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    def set_advert
      @advert = Advert.find(params[:id])
    end

    def advert_params
      params.require(:advert).permit(:title, :content, :category_jobtype_id, :category_positiontype_id, :salarystart, :salaryend, :category_country_id, :city, :town, :postcode, :category_editorialapproval_id, :category_applicationrequest_id, :category_advert_id, :userr_id )
    end
end
```

Comment: Look at app/views/shared/_header_recruiter.html.erb:6.
Try to use `new_userr_advert(params[:userr_id])` instead of `new_userr_advert`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you don't have a `advert.userr` object. The easiest way to check that is to print it.

So temporarily, remove your `link` and print the `userr`

```
<% @adverts.each do |advert| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= advert.created_at.strftime("%B %d, %Y") %></td>
      <td><%= link_to advert.title, '#' %></td>
      <td><%= advert.content %></td>
      <td><%= advert.city %></td>
      <td><%#= link_to 'Show', userr_advert_path(advert.userr, advert) %></td>
       <td><%= advert.userr.inspect %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
```

So if you can;t see anything, that means your relations between `userr` and `advert` is not setup correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The error notifies that There is no userr_id in the url which means that advert object does not have userr object or you may forgot to enter userr_id while manually typing the url.